# SignalReleaseStrategy for aggregator in spring integration

Tags: spring-integration

I have an scenario where I want to group messages using an aggregator and release them when a message arrive in another flow. Is it possible to send a signal to the aggregator to release the group?

thanks in advance!
Guzmán

Comment: Try yourself, show code. If you can't, your question is off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the only way to do something like this is to send a "dummy" completion message to the aggregator, have the release strategy based on its presence and remove it from the released collection (payload).